# hr element vs 1px high div vs 1px border

Tags: html, css

I have an app which has sections, and I need a 1px line between them.  It seems I have a choice:

1. An hr element.
2. A div with a 1px border.
3. A div which is one pixel high, and has a background color.

See [example](https://codepen.io/gregoryagu/pen/zoQEyz)

```
.hr1{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.hr2{
  height:1px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

Is there any benefit to one particular way?

It seems to me the hr element is not a good idea, as the styling could get changed too easily.

Comment: Depending on your context it might simply make sense to add a bottom border on containing sectioning elements. The main difference will be in semantics, a `hr` means a _"thematic break"_ between paragraphs, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr).

Comment: This seems to be primarily opinion based, but I would say:

**1.** `<hr />` will be an extra tag.
**2.** `border` will be easily styleable using CSS.

Comment: @Nit, I actually tried that, but there are many nested divs on the page.  I need to put the hr between the higher level divs, or it doesn't span the page.

Comment: This also looks like it's something to do with the UX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is one overwhelming advantage to using the proper `hr` element: it is understood by text-based browsers and screen readers.

To someone who doesn't use a normal browser, an empty `div` will not show at all, whether or not there is a border. An `hr` always will. It's probably desirable for it to do so.

More information is available [on this accessibility site](http://diveintoaccessibility.info/day_25_using_real_horizontal_rules_or_faking_them_properly.html), which also notes a suggestion for times when you *need* to use something other than an `hr`:

```html
<div class="rule"></div><hr>
```

```css
div.rule {
    height: 1px;
    background: blue;
}
hr {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That is very interesting.  I had not thought about the accessibility aspect of the situation.  But of course you are right.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @lonesomeday's answer:  The correct use of the HR element is important to screenreaders, and text-based browsers.  This example is given from the spec:

*Some examples of thematic breaks that can be marked up using the hr element include a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book.*

The use case in the question is presentational, not thematic. So it would not add a benefit to a text-based browser, or screen reader.  So an hr element should not be used in this case.